# Spring security: remember-me cookie is created in the browser but password is not saving

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-java-config, remember-me

I am implementing a remember me in my web app using Java config which does not works. I have gone through all the similar questions and found no solution to my issue.

Here is the code:

```
@Bean
    public PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices getPersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices() {
        PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices tokenBasedservice = new PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices(
                "remember-me", userDetailsService, tokenRepository);
//        tokenBasedservice.setAlwaysRemember(true);
//        tokenBasedservice.setCookieName("remeber-me");
        return tokenBasedservice;
    }


@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.
                 .....
                    .and().formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .failureUrl("/login-error")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                    .usernameParameter("username")
                    .passwordParameter("password")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                    .and().logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and()
                    .rememberMe().rememberMeParameter("remember-me").tokenRepository(tokenRepository)
                    .tokenValiditySeconds(86400).and().csrf().and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access_denied");
        }
```

This is the html created using thymeleaf

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
    <h3>Login</h3>
    <div th:if="${loginError}"
         th:class="'alert alert-'+ *{loginError.type.name}+' alert-dismissible'">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×
        </button>
        <span><b th:text="*{loginError.description}"></b></span>
    </div>
    <form id="login-form" th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Username</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder=""
                       name="username"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Password" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="Password"
                       name="password"
                       placeholder=""/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <div class="pull-left m-r-20 checkbox icheck">
                    <div class="checkbox icheck">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="remember-me" id="remember-me"/> Remember Me
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
.........
```

Can anyone figure out the issue?

UPDATE:

When inspecting the code using chrome, I can see remember-me cookie in the list of cookies. So the cookie exists but could not be retrieved at the right place. What causes these kind of scenarios? Is this problem in my code or server side?

[image: screen capture 1]

[image: screen capture 2]

Comment: Can any one give idea?

Comment: Try adding these in spring security

.rememberMeCookieName("remember-me")
                .key("remember-me")
                .rememberMeParameter("remember-me")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the configuration file you have given

```
rememberMeParameter("remember-me")
```

But in your html

```
<input type="checkbox"/> Remember Me
```

Spring security is not getting the parameter 'remember-me'. Try putting "remember-me" as the name in html for the checkbox. Hope that helps.

Comment: Are you sure that 'remember-me' is being passed to spring security, the whole form , not only username and password?

Comment: If you can see the cookie as 'remember-me' then add this in config. '.rememberMeCookieName("remember-me")'

Comment: Nothing happens

Comment: How do I check whether the whole form is being passed

Comment: You can check the submit function, are you using the form submit or a custom function which passes only username and password?

Comment: No, whole form is passed using post method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158469/discussion-between-sndu-and-don).